# Find $\delta$ such that if $0<\vert x - 2 \vert < \delta$ then $\vert f(x) - 1 \vert < 0.01$

Tags: calculus

Given the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x-1}$, find $\delta$ such that if $0<\vert x - 2 \vert < \delta$ then $\vert f(x) - 1 \vert < 0.01$.

Here is my attempt:

We need to find $\delta$ such that $\delta$ implies $\vert f(x) - 1 \vert = \vert \frac{1}{x-1} -1 \vert < 0.01$.

That is we need $\delta$ to imply
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{100} &< \frac{1}{x-1}-1 < \frac{1}{100}\\
\frac{99}{100} &< \frac{1}{x-1} < \frac{101}{100}\\
\frac{100}{99} &> x-1 > \frac{100}{101}\\
\frac{1}{99} &> x-2 > -\frac{1}{101}.
\end{align*}

Thus let $\delta = \frac{1}{101}$. Now let us assume $0<\vert x - 2 \vert < \delta = \frac{1}{101}$. Then

\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{101} &< x-2 < \frac{1}{101}\\
-\frac{1}{101} &< x-2 < \frac{1}{99}\\
\frac{100}{101} &< x-1 < \frac{100}{99}\\
\frac{101}{100} &> \frac{1}{x-1} > \frac{99}{100}\\
-\frac{1}{101} &< \frac{1}{x-1}-1  < \frac{1}{101}.\\
\end{align*}

And thus $\vert \frac{1}{x-1} -1 \vert < 0.01$.

Doe this work to show what is being asked/is my answer correct? Moreover, I'm wondering if this is the easiest approach or if there is an easier method I should be taking advantage of. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it seems correct to me